# Terminal potential difference of cell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, batteries

I was given two cell X and Y of emfs 6V and 4V and internal resistance 2ohm and 8 ohm respectively connected in series with an external resistor of resistance 10 ohm and asked to find terminal potential difference across each cell. The terminal potential difference across Y was found to be 0. What does it mean by 0 terminal potential difference in a closed circuit?

Answer (score 0):

The potential difference for the terminal, not for circuit. I hope that's what you are trying to mean. It means that all of the cell potential is dropped across the internal resistance.